# Is there an algorithm to transform a generic arithmetic formula to another one using arbitrary rules?

Tags: algorithm, parsing, tree, formula, brackets

I'm trying to develop a program where the user would be able to select parts of a given arithmetic formula or expression and also selects a single transformation rule from a given set of transformation rules, and the program would transform the formula accordingly, if possible.

I have built expression trees to the formulas and the transformation rules but I can't figure out how to use them to achieve my goal.

For example:
If I have the following formula 
`a * (b * c) + a - c`
And the user have selected this sub-formula `a * (b * c)`
And also selected this transformation rule `X * ( Y * Z ) ≡ Y * ( X * Z)`

Then the expected result should be `b * ( a * c ) + a - c`

Is there an algorithm that could make this transformation even when there are brackets in the expression/rule?

Comment: Convert the expression to a syntax tree and then do tree pattern matching. (Google will find you lots of references.)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to learn about is ["program transformation systems" (PTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation).
These tools accept source code, and explicit "rules" that tell it how to manipulate the code.  (Rici's comment is an ever-so brief description of the technology used to implement a PTS.)

Using arbitrary rules is likely to produce nonsense.  What people tend to write are rules that preserve the semantics of the program.   But a good PTS will accept whatever rules you provide and apply them.   PTS + rules == OP's "algorithm".

"Formulas" are a subset of "programs", so a PTS that can transform code can also transform formulas.

For a completely worked example of a PTS configured with rules to solve algebra and some simple calculus, see my example of [Algebra as a DMS domain](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/SimpleDMSDomainExample.html).   DMS is a commercial PTS that I have designed and built over the last 23 years.